# How to extend volume using powershell?

Tags: powershell, wmi, disk

How to extend volume using powershell (I prefer WMI over powershell remoting) on remote computer ?

OS is win XP sp3.

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: More like Server Fault, I guess. I won't vote to close, though, as then it would end up where I think I belongs less than here ;-)

Comment: How is a scripting question super user? I'm sure it would be fine for Server Fault, but there are lots of PowerShell questions here. Seems like it belongs here to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up with somethin like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $compName -Credential $compCred -ScriptBlock {"rescan","select volume 2","extend" | diskpart}
```

I'm still looking for better solution, if there is one.

Comment: Should be noted that winrm must be running on the destination machine for this command to execute.

Comment: This is really clever and cool. I upvoted it for that reason, but I think my answer is closer to what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of scripts Microsoft's Storage Team wrote to handle this that can also be hooked into System Insights as automated remediation actions:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2018/06/19/creating-remediation-actions-for-system-insights/

You can also [see my answer with PowerShell function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998751/1040437) here, in [Remotely extend a partition using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976411/remotely-extend-a-partition-using-wmi):